# MariaDB INNER JOIN with foreign keys are MUCH slower than without them

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Please help me, I'm stuck with the strange behaviour of MariaDB server.
I have 3 tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `default_work` (
  `add_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_text` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `downloads` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `default_work_subject_id_IDX` (`subject_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `default_work_work_type_id_IDX` (`work_type_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `default_work_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `default_subject` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `default_work_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`work_type_id`) REFERENCES `default_worktype` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=210673 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `default_subject` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `old_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject_literal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `default_worktype` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `work_type_literal` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `multiple` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `default_worktype_old_id_a8b508fe_uniq` (`old_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `default_worktype_work_type_literal_1e609434_uniq` (`work_type_literal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

These tables were created by Django ORM but it seems to be ok.
The **default_work** table has about 200,000 records, **default_subject** - 42, and **default_worktype** - 12.

After I was making a request in Django admin with simple joins between those tables I've got about 9 secs of query time.
Looked in SQL log I've found a raw query:

```sql
SELECT `default_work`.`id`, `default_work`.`title`, `default_worktype`.`work_type`,`default_subject`.`subject`
FROM `default_work`
INNER JOIN `default_subject` ON (`default_work`.`subject_id` = `default_subject`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `default_worktype` ON (`default_work`.`work_type_id` = `default_worktype`.`id`) 
ORDER BY `default_work`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

The explain showing:
[Explain result of the query with indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyADg.png)

And this is a bit confusing because when I deleted all indexes on table **default_work** except the primary key, the results were completely different. The request time was about 3.4 msec and explain shows the all primary keys are used correctly.
[Explain result of the query without indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDR5v.png)

PS. I'm tried to reproduce this situation on PostgreSQL and got a 1.3 msec with the request with indexes and foreign keys.

Comment: So what does SQL Server do here? is it related? Please do not tag irrelevant tags.

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Deleted.

Comment: Sounds like a good example of where the Optimizer fails to make use of `LIMIT` in deciding on the query plan.  Please file a bug with jira.mariadb.com

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your EXPLAIN results you can see that when the foreign keys are turned on the system is using that key in the join, instead of choosing to use the primary key in the target table. (row 2)

As there will be many records with the same value it massivley increases the records that are being evaluated.

I don't know why it's choosing to do that.  You may find that rewriting the select statement in a different order will change how it chooses the indexes.  You may find the choice is different if in the ON clause you secify target table first then the source table (`default_subject`.`id` = `default_work`.`subject_id`)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand why MySql don't use primary keys as PostgresSQL do. Looking on PgSQL in comparison to MySQL make me think it's time to change my favourite DB engine.

Comment: No, I don't know why it's choosing to do that either. On the bright side though it looks like human minds are still required!